# HtmlUnit not running all HTTP Requests in parallel ??

Tags: java, htmlunit, snapshot

I use HtmlUnit to create Page Snapshots, to be used for various purposes. What i found out was that HtmlUnit is not sending requests in parallel, as it happens in browser (6 parallel requests at a time). Can somebody help me with this ?

My code :-

```
    wc = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME);

    //wc.setAjaxController(new NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController());
    //wc.getOptions().setCssEnabled(true); 
    //wc.setCssErrorHandler(new SilentCssErrorHandler());

    wc.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false); 
    wc.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false); 
    wc.getOptions().setRedirectEnabled(false);
    //wc.getOptions().setAppletEnabled(true); 
    wc.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);  
    wc.getOptions().setPrintContentOnFailingStatusCode(false);
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you can't achieve it now.

According to [HtmlUnit docs](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/WebClient.html)

> In the future downloads should be performed in parallel in separated
>   threads.

Looks like that the future not arrived yet. But you always can try to implement a patch if it's so important for you then send it to the upstream.

Comment: Thanks Pavel. Could you guide me to a substitute solution ? I cannot PhantomJS or prerender.io because they do not support ajax. So, i need a headless browser in a definite sense.

Comment: If you use any flavour of Unix, you may try to switch Firefox or Chrome in [XVFB](https://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.6/doc/man/man1/Xvfb.1.xhtml), so it would be headless. What about Windows - I have no idea.

Comment: Hi Pavel, Thanks again!